# Different List return types on abstract method

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I am trying to separate return types from database function calls with subclasses of an abstract Output class.  I am running into an issue where my abstract method (getResults) return type needs to be different for a ResultSet from a Date, or char, or string but they should all fall under an Output class or interface.  The subclass that returns the ResultSet needs to return a `List<Map<String,Object>>`, Date should return `List<Date>`, String `List<String>`, etc...

Client Code:

```
LoadableStatement loadedStatementObject= new LoadableStatement.Builder()
            .addParam(new In(2, 111111))
            .addParam(new Out(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR))
            .addStatement(DBPackage.LOOKUP_RECORD.getStatement())
            .load();
Output cursor = new Cursor(loadedStatementObject);
```

abstract method in Output.java and subclasses of.

```
public class Output{
    //Constructor, fields etc...
    public abstract Collection getResults();
}


public class Cursor extends Output {
    private List<Map<String, Object>> results;

    public Cursor(LoadableStatement statement) {
        super(statement);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection getResults() {
        //Logic to convert some type of list from DB into a 
        //List<Map<String,Object>>
        return new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    }
}

public class StringResult extends Output {

    public StringResult(LoadableStatement statement) {
        super(statement);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection getResults() {
    //Logic that converts a list from DB into a List<String>
    }

}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using generics, albeit incorrectly i am sure.  I have tried List<?>, Collection<? extends E>, List<Object>.  I am pretty sure generics could solve my problem, but I don’t know how to use them correctly.

Comment: Then share what you have done too.

Comment: Ravindra, I have added code.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public class LoadableStatement {}

public abstract class Output<E> {
  //Constructor, fields etc...
  public abstract Collection<E> getResults();
  public Output(LoadableStatement statement) {
    /* Some implementation ... */
  }

}

public class Cursor extends Output<Map<String, Object>> {
  private List<Map<String, Object>> results;

  public Cursor(LoadableStatement statement) {
    super(statement);
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<Map<String, Object>> getResults() {
    //Logic to convert some type of list from DB into a 
    //List<Map<String,Object>>
    return new ArrayList<>();
  }
}

public class StringResult extends Output<String> {

  public StringResult(LoadableStatement statement) {
    super(statement);
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<String> getResults() {
    //Logic that converts a list from DB into a List<String>
    return new ArrayList<>();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a generic version of Output class. Which has a generic function with a generic return type. Here is some sample code:

```
public class Output<T>{
//fields and constructor
public T getResults(); 
}
```

here T is for Type you can use any identifier.

Note: While using collections please keep in mind that primitives are not allowed in a collection.